# Strange issue on netadapter lantronix matchport bgpro

Tags: local-area-network, ethernet, embedded, evolution

I'm connected to a switch on a LAN, i've tested my matchport on others network and i've not accused this problem. On this istead i seen a lot of UP and DOWN of eht0 on startup.

Someone know something about this?

```
 # Sv Filename    Line Description                                    Uptime
---- - ---------- ----- ---------------------------------------------- --------
   4 I start.c      234 5.2.0.3R2                                      00:00:00
   5 I start.c      235 Oct  5 2012 (11:54:32)                         00:00:00
   6 I start.c      241 Image Name: matchport_bg_pro                   00:00:00
   7 I start.c      243 Query Port Id: A9                              00:00:00
   8 I start.c      245 Heap size: 5567904                             00:00:00
   9 I start.c      272 i2c init                                       00:00:00
  10 I start.c      287 # serial ports: 2/2                            00:00:00
  11 I start.c      303 cpm init                                       00:00:00
  12 I start.c      312 timeout init                                   00:00:00
  13 I start.c      315 event server init                              00:00:00
  14 I start.c      318 flash init                                     00:00:00
  15 I flash.c      379 flash mfg=0x20 dev=0x227E, model=0x2210        00:00:00
  16 I flash.c      434 using flash driver "AMD Generic"               00:00:00
  17 I start.c      321 config manager init                            00:00:00
  18 I start.c      324 filesystem init                                00:00:00
  19 I fastfile.c   379 FW: 2-49  A: 50-88  B: 89-127  SZ: 65536       00:00:00
  20 I fastfile.c   494 using bank A 00320000-0058FFFF                 00:00:00
  21 I fastfile.c   522 rt=003200AC st=0x3 sz=0x0 nxt=FFFFFFFF         00:00:00
  22 I start.c      348 cfg flash init                                 00:00:00
  23 I cfgflash.c  1969 Found configuration file                       00:00:00
  24 I start.c      351 cpu init                                       00:00:00
  25 I start.c      358 oem init                                       00:00:00
  26 I start.c      367 serial init                                    00:00:00
  27 I start.c      370 dns init                                       00:00:00
  28 I start.c      373 network init                                   00:00:00
  29 I net.c        451 active network interface: eth0                 00:00:00
  30 I net.c        534 eth0 mac: 00:20:4a:c0:cf:0c                    00:00:00
  31 I start.c      394 eth0 phy init                                  00:00:00
  32 I start.c      402 snmp init                                      00:00:00
  33 I start.c      406 dynamic ip start                               00:00:00
  34 I start.c      410 supplicant init                                00:00:00
  35 I start.c      420 pio reset monitor                              00:00:00
  36 I start.c      425 mib init                                       00:00:00
  37 I start.c      429 ftp init                                       00:00:00
  38 I start.c      432 tftp init                                      00:00:00
  39 I start.c      436 syslog init                                    00:00:00
  40 I start.c      449 ssl init                                       00:00:00
  41 I start.c      453 http init                                      00:00:00
  42 I start.c      457 web init                                       00:00:00
  43 I start.c      462 rss init                                       00:00:00
  44 I start.c      469 ssh init                                       00:00:00
  45 I start.c      473 77FE init                                      00:00:00
  46 I start.c      476 tunnel init                                    00:00:00
  47 I start.c      479 terminal init                                  00:00:00
  48 I start.c      483 host init                                      00:00:00
  49 I start.c      488 cpm post init                                  00:00:00
  50 I start.c      493 email init                                     00:00:00
  51 I start.c      512 cli init                                       00:00:00
  52 I cli.c       6361 telnet cli server started                      00:00:00
  53 I cli.c       6357 ssh cli server started                         00:00:00
  54 I start.c      534 ppp init                                       00:00:01
  55 I start.c      539 modbus init                                    00:00:01
  56 I start.c      549 VIP access init                                00:00:01
  57 I start.c      557 lpd Init                                       00:00:01
  58 I start.c      579 power management init                          00:00:01
  59 I pwr_mgmt.c    94 power management audit                         00:00:01
  60 I start.c      584 calling SDK app                                00:00:01
  61 I lib_netdeb   267 Net Debug on port 7777 OK.                     00:00:01
  62 I trsmio_tes  1191 HostlinkThread start                           00:00:01
  63 I start.c      597 rtos main task finished                        00:00:01
  64 I trsmio_hos   298 Hostlink configuration file ok                 00:00:01
  65 I ethphy.c     132 eth0 link up                                   00:00:02
  66 I dynip.c      358 eth0 static ip: 192.168.12.210                 00:00:02
  67 I ethphy.c     160 eth0 link down                                 00:00:03
  68 I ethphy.c     132 eth0 link up                                   00:00:04
  69 I trsmio_tes  1209 HostlinkThread data populated                  00:00:04
  70 I ethphy.c     160 eth0 link down                                 00:00:05
  71 I ethphy.c     132 eth0 link up                                   00:00:07
  72 I ethphy.c     160 eth0 link down                                 00:00:08
  73 I ethphy.c     132 eth0 link up                                   00:00:09
  74 I ethphy.c     160 eth0 link down                                 00:00:10
  75 I ethphy.c     132 eth0 link up                                   00:00:12
  76 I ethphy.c     160 eth0 link down                                 00:00:13
  77 I ethphy.c     132 eth0 link up                                   00:00:14
  78 I ethphy.c     160 eth0 link down                                 00:00:15
  79 I ethphy.c     132 eth0 link up                                   00:00:17
  80 I ethphy.c     160 eth0 link down                                 00:00:18
  81 I ethphy.c     132 eth0 link up                                   00:00:19
  82 I ethphy.c     160 eth0 link down                                 00:00:20
  83 I ethphy.c     132 eth0 link up                                   00:00:22
  84 I ethphy.c     160 eth0 link down                                 00:00:23
  85 I ethphy.c     132 eth0 link up                                   00:00:24
  86 I ethphy.c     160 eth0 link down                                 00:00:25
  87 I ethphy.c     132 eth0 link up                                   00:00:27
  88 I ethphy.c     160 eth0 link down                                 00:00:28
  89 I ethphy.c     132 eth0 link up                                   00:00:29
  90 I ethphy.c     160 eth0 link down                                 00:00:30
  91 I ethphy.c     132 eth0 link up                                   00:00:32
  92 I ethphy.c     160 eth0 link down                                 00:00:33
  93 I ethphy.c     132 eth0 link up                                   00:00:34
  94 I ethphy.c     160 eth0 link down                                 00:00:35
  95 I ethphy.c     132 eth0 link up                                   00:00:37
  96 I ethphy.c     160 eth0 link down                                 00:00:38
  97 I ethphy.c     132 eth0 link up                                   00:00:39
  98 I ethphy.c     160 eth0 link down                                 00:00:40
  99 I ethphy.c     132 eth0 link up                                   00:00:44
 100 I ethphy.c     160 eth0 link down                                 00:00:45
 101 I ethphy.c     132 eth0 link up                                   00:00:47
 102 I ethphy.c     160 eth0 link down                                 00:00:48
 103 I ethphy.c     132 eth0 link up                                   00:00:49
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like port flapping.  There can be a few causes of that.  Among them are bad cabling and a defective NIC on either side of the cable.

Comment: Thank you in a little while i test with another cable. Do you think the problem may come from too many connection requests?

Comment: I can't imagine why that might cause a hardware failure, no.  Keep in mind that this is usually a cable, but sometimes a NIC too.